# ip can access but domain cannot access the site

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I encounter a problem when deploying an application.
after deploy I can access the site using IP but if i visit the site with domain
it fails.  when rollback the system, I can use the domain to visit the site. it's strange.
and the firebug tool shows that the request status is **'Aborted'**
[image]

My system is: centos 6.4

Comment: Have you configured dns?

Comment: we use the defalt DNS. no need to config it. when rollback the system is ok and I can access it using domain indicating the the dns is ok

Comment: yes dns seems to be the issue. Check with `ping` or `telnet` the domain name you are using. And what do you mean by "when rollback" ?

Comment: @beginer  I mean I update the site with the old version appliation by "when rollbak"

Comment: ok so what does the logs say?

Comment: @beginer I'm struggling to fingure out how to see the linux event log.Do you know how to do that?

Comment: event log?? Ok I guess I dont fully understand you. What I understand is that you are running httpd or tomcat server and you have deployed some application which works fine with IP but not with its domainname. But when you remove the application from your site, your site works fine with IP as well as domain name.

Comment: @beginer yes, that's it.

Comment: user3231931, ok so you need to look into the logs of the server you are running. The location depends on what server you are running and how you have installed it. You need to check the docs also please update the question with details about the environment you have setup.

Comment: @user3231931 thats great. I guess you should update your question such that it may be useful for other new users. Also you can upvote my comment to get me some reps  B-)   ;-)